# Upgrading wpa_supplicant to 2.6 manually on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, 17.10, wpa-supplicant

I've been trying to find an easy detailed instruction on how to upgrade the wpa_supplicant either using a script or something, or manually. I am currently running with the 2.4 version, which does have some problems with my particular wireless driver. To be more precise, the wifi disconnects in 1 minute with this following error in the dmesg: **crc RXD_W3_CIPHER_ERROR**. As far as I found out, it might be because of the 2.4 version not accepting no ca certificates... And hopefully upgrading to 2.6 version, or downgrading to 2.3 one will fix the problem. The problem is that since I am a newbie to Ubuntu, I can not really find a way to either upgrade or downgrade the wpa_supplicant on my own. I've tried some instructions on web, but they did not work. Hopefully someone will know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade your wpa_supplicant from current version to 2.6, refer the link below....

The instructions given in this link is for ubuntu 16.04, but i tried them on ubuntu 17.10 as well and so far no problem arised. Still try them at your own risk.

i'll be not responsible for any bad effects.(although which is not the case for me.it worked well without any errors at all).

if your going to try them..i suggest you to use 'sudo -s' and login as root user. then later it will come in handy when you execute 'cd /tmp' which is in the root dir. if not it will give the error directory not found.

link : http://www.linuxtopic.com/2017/08/compile-wpasupplicant-ubuntu.html

Edit:

I added below the necessary information also available on above link for the use of anyone, in case if the link may not functional anymore....

1) **Need to install few dependencies required by wpa_supplicant**

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev build-essential checkinstall  pkg-config
```

---

```
sudo apt install dbus libdbus-1-dev libdbus-glib-1-2 libdbus-glib-1-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev
```

---

```
sudo apt install libnl-genl-3-dev libnl-3-dev
```

2) **Then go to the root directory & then go to tmp folder**

```
cd /
```

---

```
cd tmp
```

3) **Download wpa_supplicant source package**

```
wget https://w1.fi/releases/wpa_supplicant-2.6.tar.gz wpa_supplicant2.6.tar.gz
```

4) **Extract  wpa_supplicant2.6.tar.gz**

```
sudo tar xvf  wpa_supplicant2.6.tar.gz
```

if this command returns a error, make sure that the name of the downloaded tar file and the name in the command are same. if the downloaded tar file's name is different from the file name in the command, it will not able to extract the file.

5) **Go in to extracted wpa_supplicant folder.**

```
cd wpa_supplicant2.6
```

Again if returns a error check whether the folder name is correct.

6) **Create a build configuration file that should work for standard WiFi setups by running the following command.**

```
cat > wpa_supplicant/.config << "EOF"
CONFIG_BACKEND=file
CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_FILE=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_SYSLOG=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_SYSLOG_FACILITY=LOG_DAEMON
CONFIG_DRIVER_NL80211=y
CONFIG_DRIVER_WEXT=y
CONFIG_DRIVER_WIRED=y
CONFIG_EAP_GTC=y
CONFIG_EAP_LEAP=y
CONFIG_EAP_MD5=y
CONFIG_EAP_MSCHAPV2=y
CONFIG_EAP_OTP=y
CONFIG_EAP_PEAP=y
CONFIG_EAP_TLS=y
CONFIG_EAP_TTLS=y
CONFIG_IEEE8021X_EAPOL=y
CONFIG_IPV6=y
CONFIG_LIBNL32=y
CONFIG_PEERKEY=y
CONFIG_PKCS12=y
CONFIG_READLINE=y
CONFIG_SMARTCARD=y
CONFIG_WPS=y
CFLAGS += -I/usr/include/libnl3
EOF
```

7) **If you use WPA Supplicant with NetworkManager 1.8.0, add the following options to the WPA Supplicant build configuration(OPTIONAL)**

```
cat >> wpa_supplicant/.config << "EOF"
CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE_DBUS=y
CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE_DBUS_NEW=y
CONFIG_CTRL_IFACE_DBUS_INTRO=y
EOF
```

8) **Compile & create package**

```
cd wpa_supplicant
```

---

```
make
```

9) **Install Wpa_supplicant & create wpa_supplicant 2.6 package**

```
checkinstall
```

This command will carry on with the installation and make a note of that the user will be required to press ENTER in several locations to proceed with the installation.

10) **Finally package created check on same directory and wpa_supplicant version check**

```
ls wpa-supplicant*
```

---

```
wpa_supplicant -v
```

Done! if everything went smoothly it should return that, the wpa_supplicant version is 2.6

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your post doesn't really give any true guidance on how to upgrade WPA Supplicant, and just really provides a link.  Such link only answers can go away whenever a website dies off or such, and as such you should really provide the key bits of information from such links in your answers.

Comment: Noted and understood. I'll add necessary information on that link.